# What datatype in C++ that is equivalent to const CURRENCY in vb6?

Tags: c++, vb6, ocx

I am writing an ATL C++ program which serves as a wrapper class of an OCX file. This will be build as dll.

**My problem:**
In OCX there's a method that accepts CURRENCY type.
Ex: 
`OCXMethodName(long a, const CURRENCY & cy);`

In my C++ code when I try to pass CURRENCY/CY type in OCXMethodName I get an error during debugging. The error is that, It is not returning 0, which means not success. Something wrong with the data.

See Ex:
`STDMETHODIMP CMethod::MyMethod(LONG var_a, CURRENCY amount)
    {
    ...
        long lRet = OCX->OCXMethodName(var_a, amount);   //This will execute in OCX
    ...
    }`

It will be build as dll and I used vbscript to further unit test it.
Ex vbscript code:
`Dim ret
    ret = objATL.MyMethod(11, 5000)    '''This will call the C++ Method`
Upon execution "Microsoft (R) Windows Based Script Host" dialog pop-up.

My question is what is the best way to handle or convert CURRENCY so I could pass the correct data type in the OCX method?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Where's the `CY` coming from? The type is literally `CURRENCY`.

Comment: Currency is a 64-bit signed integer containing values scaled by 10000 and used as a "fixed point" value with 4 decimal places.  So to multiply one by 7 you simply do a 64-bit multiply by 7 on it, and so on.  The type is `CURRENCY` in MIDL `[oleautomation]` interface definitions.

Comment: @Bob77: True, but that's implementation. As the `CURRENCY const& b` shows, this fixed-point logic is already wrapped in a C++ class.

Comment: Where did you get the definition of `OCXMethodName(long a, const CURRENCY & cy);`? How do you know it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

A currency variable is stored internally as an eight-byte long integer with four assumed decimal places.  For example, a currency value of 1.25 would be stored as 12500.  Hope this points you in the right direction.